# express firebase serve POST/GET requests respond with 404 errors

Tags: express, google-cloud-functions, http-post, firebase-tools

I am trying to send POST/GET requests after using `firebase serve`, but this always responds in an error. I have tried many things like reinstalling node, using a backslash at the end of the url, using `firebase deploy` instead, resetting firebase.json, using ThunderClient in vscode instead of Postman, turning off ssl certificate for Postman, etc.

[image: Screenshot of Postman]

Here is my index.js file:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const express = require("express");

const app = express();

const Auth = require("./util/middleware");

// enable CORS

const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());

// can't use app level middleware :(

// app.use(Auth);

const { signup, login, logout } = require("./handlers/users");

const {

  getMyBoardsOverview,

  getLeaderboard,

  createBoard,

} = require("./handlers/boards");

// user routes

app.post("/signup", signup);

app.post("/login", login);

app.post("/logout", Auth, logout);

// board routes

app.get("/boards", Auth, getMyBoardsOverview);

app.get("/board/:boardId/leaderboard", Auth, getLeaderboard);

app.post("/board", Auth, createBoard);

exports.api = functions.region("us-west2").https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Can you try opening Emulator suite in browser and see if you have anything in the logs ? Also do other endpoints respond?

Comment: @Dharmaraj The logs in the Emulator suite shows the following: [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12oMmWA8C2-RRM3H-PZc6eUZoCeo1jBm6/view?usp=sharing). Other endpoints do not respond for me; however, the `firebase serve`, http requests, and code work for my peers.